# Can't copy/paste in Word: "Word has encountered a probIem"

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, copy-paste, microsoft-word-365

Word won't let me copy/paste.

When I try to copy, Word at least *looks like* it's copying. When I select text and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the Paste button lights up in the ribbon. When I select text and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, the text disappears as expected. But when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, I get a simple error message: "Word has encountered a problem," nothing pastes, and the Paste button dims again. If I try pasting with a right-click, the paste option is unavailable. I'm similarly unable to paste from Word into Excel or Notepad or Chrome.

The problem is largely consistent throughout my use of Word. But, sometimes, if I just keep pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, and dismissing the error message over and over and over and over, it will eventually paste. But there are other times where literally a hundred attempts will do nothing to break through this behavior.

Any ideas how to fix this?

**Other possibly relevant information:**

- Restarting seems to solve the problem, but only very briefly.
- I'm seeing the same problem on multiple machines.
- The problem persists regardless of how much text I'm copying or how the text is formatted.
- I run into basically the same problem in PowerPoint. I can cut or copy from PowerPoint, but if I try to paste into Word, I get the same error: "Word has encountered a problem."
- I run into a similar problem when in Excel. There, I usually get the following error: "We could not copy the content to the Clipboard, it is in use by another application. You can still paste your content within this workbook but it will not be available in other applications." In other words, I can paste within Excel, but I can't copy from Excel and paste into Word. The error message pops when I copy, not when I paste.
- I run into a similar problem in MS Paint. There, I get the following error: "Not enough memory resources are available to process this command." The error message pops when I copy, not when I paste.
- I have recently begun to have problems copy/pasting in Windows Explorer, as well. The behavior is essentially parallel to what's happening in Word: Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> on a file grays it out like it's been cut, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> does nothing. I never get an error message. I can still move files by dragging them around.
- I do not run into problems when I'm copy/pasting within Notepad or from Notepad into Word.
- I do not run into problems when I'm copy/pasting within non-Microsoft programs or from non-Microsoft programs into Word. For instance, I can copy text in Chrome and then paste it within Chrome or into Word.
- I *think* I recently updated Office, but I don't really remember whether the problem was happening before that.

My machine is a Lenovo IdeaPad 3:

```
Processor   AMD Ryzen 7 5700U with Radeon Graphics            1.80 GHz
Installed RAM   12.0 GB (9.85 GB usable)
Device ID   347696DF-6F2C-45FE-B26D-19D5084CF8F8
Product ID  00325-97241-10301-AAOEM
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch   Touch support with 10 touch points
```

I'm running Windows 10:

```
Version 21H2
Installed on    ‎9/‎8/‎2021
OS build    19044.2846
Serial number   PF324X0L
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4190.0
```

Word says it's on Build 2303 and that the latest versions of Microsoft 365 and Office currently installed.

Comment: Have you tried a repair install of office? [Repair an Office application - Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b)

Comment: The repair install worked. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I'm genuinely wondering if this is part of the issue: "Not enough memory resources are available to process this command." Have you checked your hard drive space recently? You've only got less than 10 gigs of RAM available, and usually when a PC runs out of RAM it'll start using HDD space to run stuff, if I remember right.

My next step, if I were you, would be to uninstall Microsoft 365 and try a fresh reinstall, since the problem seems to have started there. What's puzzling is why this happens in MSPaint too. You may end up needing to do a fresh reinstall of Windows itself as well.

After you try a fresh install of Microsoft 365, if it doesn't work, try out some of the troubleshooters in the settings system menu. I'd try program compatibility as well as the windows update one, just to make sure.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).